# How to prevent page from loading when want to scroll

Tags: html, css

there is a button that when it is clicked, It scroll to the bottom of the page

```
<form action="#demo-section">
        <button id="demo"   >demo</button>
```

It is linked tho this div as below:

```
<div  id="demo-section" >
```

but when I click a page, it refresh and then go to bottom and also ? in the address bar:
http://xxxx.xx/?#demo-section

Comment: Unless you're writing an actual form, with choices that the user needs to make, or fields that the user needs to fill in, don't use a `form` for this. Instead, use an `<a href="#demo-section">` and _style_ it as a button, because that's what it is: a navigational link.

Answer (score 3):

If the "type" attribute is not mentioned, All buttons inside a form element act as type="submit". So just add the type="button" to the button and it will work.

EDIT: (As Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggest on his comment) you better use anchor tag and style it as a button if that is what your form aiming to achieve..

Comment: setting the type as you mentioned cause that button not work. I deside to use <a tag and a div to make a scrolling button

Comment: Of course. It need also move the "action" from the form to an "onclick" event etc.. Glad you choose the anchor way - it is what you mean to do anyways (-:

Comment: OK, using anchor is more simple :)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you should add the `type` attribute to the button with the value `"button"`, so changing

```html
<button id="demo"   >demo</button>
```

to

```
<button id="demo" type="button">demo</button>
```

should work as intended.

Furthermore, you can also investigate if what is needed is to use an anchor tag (`<a>`) and setting the `href` attribute to `#demo-section` instead of using a `form`. This will have the same effect, but without the element having to be a button (and without having to have a wrapping form - forms are not intended for navigation, as mentioned by Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans's comment, and thus the most correct approach would probably be this one).

Example of the mentioned method:

```
<a href="#demo-section">demo</a>
```

This will be shown as a hyperlink with text "demo" but can be changed to any other thing, including other HTML elements, thus being more flexible than using a form and a button (you can also style the anchor tag with CSS, so it can even *be* a button, if it is so desired).